# React Material onClick Collapse [Answer Updated]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an component with some list of details. Each list in the component have an Details button. when the user clicks on the button. It will display additional information  for the list. Here, i am using Material-Ui with react and i imported the Collapse component for this purpose. So, As you see my code below, when i click the details button in one list,  it will open the details for all the list. I want only to open for the list, i click. Please check my code below

Thanks in Advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


class Collapsed extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: {},
            details: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Tony Stark',
                    role: 'Iron Man' 
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Steve Rogers',
                    role: 'Captain America',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Thor',
                    role: 'God of Thunder'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    handleExpandClick = (id) => {
        const expended = this.state.expended;
        expended[id] = expended.hasOwnProperty(id) ? !expended[id] : true
        this.setState({ expended });
      }
  render() {
      const { details, expanded } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {details.map((detail)=>(
            <div key={detail.id}>
                {detail.name}
                <Button 
                    variant="contained"
                    disableRipple  
                    onClick={() => this.handleExpandClick(detail.id)}
                    aria-expanded={expanded}
                    aria-label="Show more"
                >
                    Details
                </Button>
                <Collapse in={expanded[detail.id]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    {detail.role}
                </Collapse>
            </div>    
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Collapsed
```

Comment: Hi, do you want just open the "details" or you wanna close it too ?

Comment: I need it to Close too.

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using one variable to store the "expended" value as a boolean, you can use an object with the id of each detail.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


class Collapsed extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: {},
            details: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Tony Stark',
                    role: 'Iron Man' 
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Steve Rogers',
                    role: 'Captain America',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Thor',
                    role: 'God of Thunder'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    handleExpandClick = (id) => {
        this.setState({ expanded: ...this.state.expanded, [id] : true });
      };
  render() {
      const {details, expanded} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {details.map((detail)=>(
            <div key={detail.id}>
                {detail.name}
                <Button 
                    variant="contained"
                    disableRipple  
                    onClick={()=>this.handleExpandClick(detail.id)}
                    aria-expanded={expanded}
                    aria-label="Show more"
                >
                    Role
                </Button>
                <Collapse in={expanded[detail.id]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    {detail.role}
                </Collapse>
            </div>    
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Collapsed
```

If you wanna have the possibility to close the expended detail you can use the handle function like :

```
handleExpandClick = (id) => {
  let expended = this.state.expended;
  expended = expended.hasOwnProperty(id) ? !expended[id] : true
  this.setState({ expended });
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Parsing error: Unexpected token" in the setState line for the spread operator

Comment: Do you change "expended" type in the state ?

Answer (score 2):

with hooks :

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState({});

    const handleClick = (id) => {
    setExpanded({
      ...expanded,
      [id]: !expanded[id]
    });
  }
<Collapse in={expanded[id]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
    {detail.role}
 </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import _ from 'lodash';

class Collapsed extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            details: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Tony Stark',
                    role: 'Iron Man'
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Steve Rogers',
                    role: 'Captain America',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Thor',
                    role: 'God of Thunder'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    handleExpandClick(id) {
        console.log(this.state[`expanded_${id}`]);
        this.setState({ [`expanded_${id}`]:  _.isUndefined(this.state[`expanded_${id}`])?true:!this.state[`expanded_${id}`] });
    };
    render() {
        const { details, expanded } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {details.map((detail) => (
                    <div key={detail.id}>
                        {detail.name}
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            disableRipple
                            onClick={this.handleExpandClick.bind(this,detail.id)}
                            aria-expanded={this.state[`expanded_${detail.id}`] || false}
                            aria-label="Show more"
                        >
                            Role
                </Button>
                        <Collapse in={this.state[`expanded_${detail.id}`] || false} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                            {detail.role}
                        </Collapse>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Collapsed
```