# How to prevent material-ui collapse from closing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a React web page that has a customized table built using material-ui. Each Row of this table is expandable, using a Collapse Component. Inside each Row I have a mini table which is visible or not, depending on whether the row is expanded or not. This works properly.

However, I have two little bugs, regarding the Collpase, that I can see affecting the user experience significantly.

1. Inside each one of these rows, I also have a button that can be used to open a Dialog with a map. Everytime I open this map, the expanded row closes. How can I avoid this situation? I think that there is no change to be made to the data each time the map is opened, in order to cause a rerender.
2. Inside each row I have a mini table, just like I said before. In this table I can insert/delete/edit rows. And everytime I try to do this, the expanded row is also closed. Just like in scenario 1, the row is closed, but in this case the data binded to the hooks is changed. Is there a way I can avoid this situation?

I'm using React hooks. Each Row of my main table is something like this.

```
function Row(props) {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
...
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: As requested I have a printscreen of the current state of my web application. In addition, I also have the code used to handle the click.

My code is something like this...

```
<Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
{renderMiniTable()}
</Collapse>
```

Then I have an arrow in which the Row can be expanded.

```
<TableCell>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="expand row"
              size="small"
              onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
            >
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
```

Image:[image]

EDIT 2:

I'm trying the event.stopPropagation() approach. Currently I have this in my onClick which opens the Dialog.

```
<div className="roomIcon">
                      <RoomIcon
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          e.stopPropagation();
                          handleClickOpen(props, e);
                        }}
                      ></RoomIcon>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try using Event.stopPropagation() on the button that opens dialog and inputs that are inside the row.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment. I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: you will need to show us how the component structure looks like and how you implemented the click handler

Comment: Thanks for you input man, I edited the main post.

Comment: I'm kinda desperate at this moment. I'm trying the approach with the event.stopPropagation() and still doesn't work. I edited the original post with what I have currently.

Comment: You must use an object with the id of each row. More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530094/react-material-onclick-collapse-answer-updated

Comment: @k3nz0 were you able to solve it ?